# Want to disable Camera features in iOS device : It is an IONIC App

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic5

I Want to disable Camera features in iOS device, as in android it won’t display the camera option when I use input type file HTML tag : It is an IONIC App

I have used this below HTML code in my ionic app for the upload image, word, excel or pdf file.

<input #fileInput type=“file” (change)=“uploadAndProgress($event.target.files, fileInput);” />

[iOS disable camera option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6tI3.jpg)

In android it ask to select the file from file photo library as expected and no camera selection. But when I see in iOS device it asks me for three option from where I have to select the one to upload the image or file. I have attached the below screenshot.

I want to remove the Take Photo or Video option from the iOS device. But, unble to find any source to do it. Can anyone please help me out with the any solution that How can I remove the “Take Photo or Video” option? In Android this option is not coming. I want only 2 option in iOS Photo Library and another one is Choose File.

I want to remove the Take Photo or Video option from the iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That is how the native OS works.